# Cookies are being blocked with my fetch call

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch-api, session-cookies

This is my fetch request:

```js
fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_DOMAIN}/auth/user/full`, { method: "GET", credentials: "include" })
```

It should send my session cookies, but im getting this error in the request cookies on network tab in chrome:

[image: Cookie error]

This means my backend doesn't recieve the cookie and thinks the user is not authenticated.

Comment: The error seems very clear. The issue is in how the cookie is set. Change this and it should work again.

Answer (score 0):

So it was my backend cookie settings. I tried to set sameSite: false (what it says in the docs of cookie) but turns out proper way is sameSite: "none". The library i use is cookie-session which refer you to cookie docs for sameSite.